# Determine the general orientation of a 2D vector

Tags: vector, 2d

I have a rather simple question for you..
I feel like I should have found the answer a long time ago but somehow I can't wrap my head around this trivial problem.

Given a vector v = (x,y) , I would like to know it's 'general' orientation. That is either 'Up', 'Down', 'Left' or 'Right'

A vector's general orientation is 'Up' if a Vector's orientation is between 45 and 135 degrees. 'Left' is between 135 and 225 degrees. 'Down' is between 225 and 315 degrees. 'Right' is between 315 and 45 degrees.

I don't really care for the cases where the angle is exactly 45, 135, 225 or 315 degrees.

The catch is, I don't want to use trigonometry. I'm pretty sure there's a simple solution.

I think a solution could split the whole circle in eight. Here's what I have so far.

```
if(x > 0 && y > x)
    return Up
if(x > 0 && y > 0 && y < x )
    return Right

... etc ...
```

Basically, I know I could find a solution. I'm more interested in your own approach to this problem.

Thanks !

**EDIT** : The vector used is not normalized. You can represent any vector using a pair of points. Simply pretend the origin of the vector is (0,0).

Comment: Okay, I may be confused, but how are you representing a vector as an x and y, then comparing x to y as if they were both positional? Shouldn't one be the direction and the other by the magnitude?

Comment: @Michael: There are two ways to represent a Vector. You can either have a direction and a magnitude (like an angle and the hypotenuse of a right triangle). The other way is to use x and y components, like the legs of the right triangle. As the OP is trying to avoid trig, the x/y approach seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Micheal: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector

Comment: Thanks. It's obviously been far too long since I took a math class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a way, indeed. All you have to realize is that if abs(y) > abs(x), then the direction is vertical, otherwise the direction is horizontal. If vertical, the sign on y will indicate up/down, otherwise, the sign on x will indicate left/right. So:

```
if (abs(y) > abs(x)) {
  if (y > 0) up else down
} else {
  if (x > 0) right else left
}
```

The 45ish angles will always go left or right.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I need. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Accepting the answer only gives +10 rep, where-as if I vote it up you also get +10, so really you want votes over answer ticks, unless your collecting badges.

Comment: Why not both? I agree it's the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you wanted to avoid trig, but have you ever used the [atan2](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/atan2/) function? It's super easy to use for determining the angle of a vector:

```
double ldAngle = atan2(vector.y, vector.x) * 180 / PI;
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But as the question stated, I don't want to use trig. I'm simply trying for a different approach since I don't need to know the exact angle, just the general orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a normalized vector space (**Edit:** meaning your vector is composed of [unit vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector)) as you appear to be doing, your approach is spot on and the one most often used for 2d games and animations. I'd verify your truth table, however.

@Daniel's approach is the more elegant IMO.

Comment: The approach should work for any vector. The vector is not normalized.

Comment: Sorry, I edited and I have read your edit. I didn't mean the vector was normalized (having a length of 1) but that it was composed of unit vectors, i.e. within a normalized vector space. Which is exactly what you are doing. We're talking the same with different terms, is all. :)